# How to use get/set properties from one class to another

Tags: c#

I am working C# code and I am stuck at a place. I have a class that have following get and set methods

```
private double value1;
private double value2;
private double value3;

public double Value1
{
   get
    {
        return value1;
    }
    set 
    {
        value1 = value;
    }
}

public double Value2
{
   get
    {
        return value2;
    }
    set 
    {
        value2 = value;
    }
}

public double Value3
{
   get
    {
        return value3;
    }
    set 
    {
        value3 = value;
    }
}
```

I have following method in the same class

```
public double CalcValue (double value1, double value2, double value3)
{
    double finalValue = value1* Math.Pow((1 + value2 / 100), value3);
    return finalValue ;
}
```

Now I have form1.cs class where there are some controls on form from which I am getting this value1, value2 and value3. So I am doing this in that class and wants to call the CalcValue function in this class...

```
double value1 = Convert.ToDouble(numUpDown_value1.Value);
double value2 = Convert.ToDouble(numUpDown_value2.Value);
double value3= Convert.ToDouble(numUpDown_value3.Value);
lbl_result.Text = obj.CalcValue(value1, value2, value3).ToString();
```

In my code, I dont find any use for the get and set methods that I set... My question is, how can I perform my function using get and set methods without using conventional method parameters as I did in CalcValue method.

Comment: Note that you don't need the backing fields and you can use autoproperties instead (the backing fields still exist, but the compiler creates them for you at build). You can simply write `public double Value1 { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your class as:

```
internal class MyObject
{
    public double Value1 { get; set; }

    public double Value2 { get; set; }

    public double Value3 { get; set; }

    public double CalculatedValue =>
        value1* Math.Pow((1 + value2 / 100), value3);
}
```

Then use it with:

```
var obj = new MyObject
{
    Value1 = Convert.ToDouble(numUpDown_value1.Value),
    Value2 = Convert.ToDouble(numUpDown_value2.Value),
    Value3 = Convert.ToDouble(numUpDown_value3.Value),
};

lbl_result.Text = obj.CalculatedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Get` and `Set` of a property are called implicitly when calling the property e.g.

```
public class Form
{
    private double value1 = 5;

    public double Value1 { 
        get {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting Value")
            return value1;
        }
        set {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting Value")
            value1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var myForm = new Form();

// calls Form.Value1.Get
// prints "Getting Value"
// prints "5.0"
Console.WriteLine(myForm.Value1) 

// calls Form.Value1.Set
// prints "Setting Value"
myForm.Value1 = 10.5;

// calls Form.Value1.Get
// prints "Getting Value"
// prints "10.5"
Console.WriteLine(myForm.Value1)
```